# Error getting text when looping though webelement using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Using selenium I would like to extract text however when switching from elements to element in the xpath I get into trouble with handling the created list correclty and beeing able to extract the text.

I tried working with xpath in the loop as well as with excluding the loop.

My current code for scraping is the following:

```
driver.get(startURLpart1 + str(pageSelections[x]))
time.sleep(10)
name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="company-list"]')
name = name.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="item"]')

for i in name:
  companyname = i.find_element_by_xpath('p').text
  print[companyname]
```

Before I tried the following with equaly less sucess:

```
for x in range(len(pageSelections)):

    driver.get(startURLpart1 + str(pageSelections[x]))
    time.sleep(10)
    name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="company-list"]')
    name = name.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="item"]')
    name = name.find_element_by_xpath('p')

    for i in name:
      companyname = i.text
      print[companyname]
```

The html of the website I am working on looks as follows:

```
<div class="company-list">
  <div class="item">
    <a href="/profiel/abc" class="title c-text">abc</a>
    <p>DFE street,  1111 Dreamland</p>

  </div><div class="item">
    <a href="/profiel/sheep" class="title c-text">xyz</a>
    <p>Wupsidupsiland,  2222 Hanutaland</p></div>
```

The result I was expecting or hoping to get here is the text out of line p for each item in the company list. (in reality there are significant more item rows in the company list).
So my expected result would be:

```
DFE street, 1111 Dreamland
Wupsidupsiland, 2222 Hanutaland
```

I hope then to be able to adjust my code to get me the text also out of row a but first i would like to fix p.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Why don`t you want to use just: name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="company-list"]/div[@class="item"]/p')

Comment: @DainiusPreimantas thanks alot that in connection with a loop including the .text comment got me my result. Could you explain me why my code didnt work because for me it seems like you just aggregated my 3 lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with xpath.
When we try to find an element inside another element it should be having a period at the beginning of xpath. This will limit your search to the children of the WebElement.
Instead of

```
name = name.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="item"]')
```

you should be using

```
name = name.find_elements_by_xpath('.//div[@class="item"]')
```

Good Luck.